# Makefile Stops Building Files After First .o In Out-of-Source Build

Tags: c, makefile

I have a bit of a huge Makefile that basically works as I want it to.

**Issue:** The problem I'm having is that the makefile only checks if the first `.o` needs updating and not if any others do. I'm not sure what part of my makefile is in error.

**Context:** I have project structure like this:

```
quendor
  src
    main.c
    options.c
    quendor.h
Makefile
```

When my Makefile builds, it constructs a `build` directory and things look as follows:

```
quendor
  build
    src
      main.d
      main.o
      options.d
      options.o
  src
    main.c
    options.c
    quendor.h
Makefile
```

**To See the Problem:** Now let's say I don't change my `main.c` but I do change my `options.c` file. In that case, when I run make again I get this:

```
make: 'build/./src/main.o' is up to date.
```

I'm not sure if this is because it's building into a `build/src` directory rather than just `build` as I intended.

Here is the full Makefile and I'm including all of it just because I'm not sure what might be a problem and I don't want to make unwarranted assumptions.

```
.PHONY : all clean

NAME := quendor
PLATFORM := windows

CC := gcc
LINK := gcc

BUILD_DIR ?= ./build
SRC_DIR ?= ./src

ifeq ($(PLATFORM), windows)
    TARGET ?= quendor.exe
else
    TARGET ?= quendor
endif

ifeq ($(CC), gcc)
    CFLAGS += -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wconversion -Wmissing-prototypes -Wshadow -MMD -MP
    LDFLAGS +=
    OPT +=
endif

SRCS := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c)
OBJS := $(SRCS:%.c=$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o)
DEPS := $(OBJS:%.o=%.d)

MKDIR_P ?= @mkdir -p $(dir $@)

-include $(DEPS)

all : $(TARGET)
    @echo "Building $(TARGET)"

$(TARGET) : $(OBJS)
    $(LINK) $(OPT) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o : %.c
    $(MKDIR_P)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    $(RM) $(TARGET) -r $(BUILD_DIR)
```

This may be an artifact of how StackOverflow is parsing my Makfile but I do notice that it's showing different syntax highlighting after this line:

```
SRCS := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c)
```

Comment: Did you already try to remove the leading `./` in your definitions of `BUILD_DIR` and `SRC_DIR`?

Comment: I hadn't but I just tried it and I get the exact same problem. To be clear what I tried, I used `BUILD_DIR ?= build` and `SRC_DIR ?= src`. But doing that still displayed the same behavior.

Comment: Can you try moving the `-include $(DEPS)` to the end of your makefile (or at the very least to a point *after* the `all` target rule).  Alternatively, trying invoking make as `make all` explicitly.

Comment: Sorry, I read a bit too quickly your question. So, make tells you that `main.o` is up to date. Guess what? make is right. As you did not change `main.c` there is  no need to recompile it. What you should see, however, is `option.c` being recompiled and `quendor.exe` relinked. Is it what you see?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Correct, I am not seeing `options.c` being recompiled even when it's changed. It just stops at `main.c` because it sees it is up to date. I was sure if this was because one of my rules wasn't allowing something recursive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are including the dependencies before you define the `all` rule:

```
-include $(DEPS)

all : $(TARGET)
```

If you don't specify a particular target to build on the command line (e.g., if you don't run `make all`) then make chooses the first explicit target in the makefile (and any included makefiles!!) as the target to build.

I assume that the dependency definitions in the `$(DEPS)` variable define `main.o` as a target and since that comes before `all`, it's the only thing that's run by default.

Move the `-include` statement later in the makefile (I typically put these all at the end of the makefile) and it will work.

Comment: AHH! That was it! I can't believe I didn't figure that out. I was reading so many sources on Makefiles and I just didn't clue in that the positioning here mattered. This entirely solved the problem and I thank you.